# How do we know if spacetime is bent?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, experimental-physics, curvature

For example I'm at certain location in outer space.

How do I know if the spacetime in front of me is bent, e.g. by some dark matter?

Comment: Suppose you are looking at a reflection in a mirror — for example, the reflection of the shoreline across a lake in the reflection of a shiny car door. How do you know whether the car door is flat or curved?

Comment: In the title, you correctly write *spacetime*. In the question, you switch to *space*. The two terms are not interchangeable.

Comment: Carry a gravity gradiometer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_gradiometry#Gravity_gradiometers

Comment: Hi rob. Um... Yes, exactly. Even if the reflection of shoreline is straight, it can be due to both curved car door and the curved shoreline? Are you trying to point out that we can't tell?

Comment: Hi @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90, thanks! Edited now.

Comment: Hi @JohnDoty. So it's kind of a direct measurement. Do you know some other methods that is indirect? I'm actually considering a non-physics-related problem -> a multidimensional space that is not flat but I want to characterize how bent at which place of the space.

Comment: @JohnnyTam Well, remotely you can look at trajectories: orbits and gravitational lensing.

Answer (score 4):

Bent spacetime will cause light beams to curve as they pass through it. Those curved paths will produce *lensed replicas* of the original light source, which show up as multiple images of the source or as smeared arcs of light. These are easily seen in Hubble deep-space images and demonstrate the existence of mass concentrations very far away from us that we cannot see.

For things closer to us (like the sun), starlight from stars very near the "edge" of the sun's photosphere gets bent in the same manner, and if we know beforehand the exact location of those stars when the sun is not nearly occluding them then we can directly measure the amount of bend.

Comment: If you can see the surroundings, then this is the better answer. If you can not see your surroundings (e.g. trapped in a windowless box), you'll have to default to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following is all hypothetical and would require an unrealistic level of measuring precision for what I'm going to describe. Realistically, these experiments would all be far better done by sophisticated tools, but I'm going to explain the underlying concepts through basic experiments to make it easier to make sense of what would need to be done.

---

You'll need a compass.

Shake the compass around and then let it rest to find the direction of any local magnetic field. Do this a few times, and if the result varies, then there is no magnetic field. If it isn't varying, then take note of how quickly it spins to the correct orientation, which tells you the magnitude of the magnetic field if one is present.

Now release the compass. Take note of if it moves and its direction of travel and acceleration if it does so. Now go collect the compass and impart an electric charge on it. Release the compass again. If the results of these two trials vary in any way other than what would be predicted by the previously determined magnetic field, then there is an electric field present. If there is, then you can use how the motion varied to determine the direction and magnitude of the electric field.

If the compass didn't move at all during that last part, then there's no gravitational field either. If it did move, then using what we know about the electric and magnetic fields and the charge on the compass, you can calculate the Lorentz force that would be incurred onto the compass. Any variation from this is then due to a gravitational field present causing tidal forces.

---

Note 1: This experiment fails if you're inside a homogenous and isotropic distribution of matter like a gas cloud.

Note 2: Electric and magnetic fields do actually impart weak gravitational influences themselves as they affect the $T^{00}$ component of the stress-energy tensor.

Comment: If the observer had a local coordinate system defined, would this method be able to recover/deduce the spacetime metric itself?

Comment: Coordinate systems have no intrinsic physical meaning. You can't use one to derive the metric.

Comment: Well, can you recover the metric in general here? Or only some partial info about it? I like this answer, so I'm curious about how much you can deduce about the spacetime from this thought experiment.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but my gut feeling is that the answer would be "no". I don't think there's enough information you could recover that would allow you to determine the metric. Maybe you could narrow things down to a family of metrics, but I'm really just guessing at this point.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll think about my question, because I think it might actually be highly nontrivial (at least to me).

Answer (score 1):

For example using atomic clock: ["A new clock shows how gravity warps time even over tiny distances"](https://www.snexplores.org/article/a-new-clock-shows-how-gravity-warps-time-even-over-tiny-distances#:%7E:text=Albert%20Einstein%27s%20theory%20of%20general,slowly%20closer%20to%20the%20ground). Bending of spacetime is an (infinitesimally) local property. It can be measured.